# how to return a value from a ajax promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a method in my angular 1.5 controller, as shown below but I wanted to refactor the ajax call into the factory itself but I'm having problems with promises..  I'm trying to get to a point where in my controller I can just call the method like I've shown below.  Is this possible?  I'm trying to avoid having the ...success(function(...)  in the controller code.

Any help much appreciated.

**Trying to move to**

```
vm.member = someFactory.getMember(vm.id);
```

**Existing working controller code**

```
vm.myMethod = myMethod;
...

function myMethod() {
    someFactory.getMember(vm.id).success(function(response) {
      vm.member = response;
    });
}
```

When I move the getMethod line into the factory the response is populated obviously but as soon as I come back to the controller, even with the return value from the factory being the response the result is undefined.  I know this is because of promises but is there a design pattern I'm missing or a clean way of doing this.  Using my currently approach my controller is littered with .success(function()...)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is called promise unwrapping.

Besides the fact that `success` is deprecated and should be replaced with `then`,

```
someFactory.getMember(vm.id).then(function(response) {
  var data = res.data;
  ...
});
```

it is totally ok to have this in controller.

The alternative to this pattern is to return self-filling object (something that ngResource `$resource` does):

```
function getMember(...) {
  var data = {};
  $http(...).then(function (response) {
    // considering that response data is JSON object,
    // it can replace existing data object
    angular.copy(data, response.data);
  });
  return data;
}
```

In this case controller can get a reference to the object instantly, and the bindings of object properties `{{ vm.member.someProperty }}` will be updated in view on response.

The pattern is limited to objects (and arrays), scalar values should be wrapped with objects.